# redis-cli info command output changes between redis 3 and redis 5

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have compared the output of "redis-cli info" between redis v3.0.3 and v5.0.5 and I see that many new values are in redis v5.0.5 but the following two are missing:

- client_longest_output_list
- client_biggest_input_buf

Are these values removed from redis 5 or just renamed to the following two, which are also new in redis v5.0.5 compared to v3.0.3?

- client_recent_max_input_buffer
- client_recent_max_output_buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These have been indeed renamed in v5 - see here https://github.com/antirez/redis/commit/be88c0b16a53f5763d8fc1ae683f99ee39b0d68e